# writing regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have been trying to write a regular expression for this but so far did not able to succeed.

```
_ any thing\_ fdfdf \_ any thing_
```

underscore then any characters until _.

`\_` is an escape character so the regular expression must accept string like this.

```
_ any \_ thing _
```

the following string:

```
checking_ happens \_ ano\_ther _ test of bold _ and escape \_asteric
```

should give:

```
_ happens \_ ano\_ther _
```

So far I am only able to come up with this:

```
(\\_)|_[^_]*[\\_]*[_]
```

Comment: Could you be more clear about input and desired output?

Comment: Could you be more specific?
Do you want _ any _ thing _ to return **any _ thing** or just **any** ?

Comment: Are you having problems with the stackoverflow markdown? If you indent your examples 4 spaces the markdown won't touch the underscores or backslashes.

Comment: Thanks @Eric I was facing problems with the stackoverflow markdown. I have added some more details in the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*_((?:[^_\\]|\\.)+)_
```

Breaking it up:

- `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*` - Match an even number of backslashes not preceded by more backslashes
- `_` - followed by an underscore
- `((?:[^_\\]|\\.)+)` - Match either of the following 1 or more times

  - `[^_\\]` - Any character except an underscore or backslash
  - `\\.` - Any backslash / character pair (e.g. `\_` or `\\`)
- `_` - Match the trailing underscore

This will capture the string between the underscores in its first group.

Comment: Thanks once again @Eric. nice thought for neglecting \\ at start using (?<!\\)
Can you please explain me what ?: does. I tried to read on the internet but did not able to get it completely.

Comment: `(?:...)` is the same as `(...)`, but without making a capturing group. Also, I don't neglect ``\\`` at the start: `\\_ test _` will fail.

Comment: @hajidon: Ok, now it works for `\\_ test_` and `\\\\_ test_` Note that it will match the leading backslashes as well...